# Pause and Resume animation(thread.sleep) in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to pause and resume my animation. Unfortunately, I am just able to pause it by using `Thread.sleep();` and unable to resume it where it was stopped. Can anyone tell me how to pause and resume a `Thread` with an animation?

This is how I currently pause it:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {

}

y++; 
Panel.repaint();
```

Comment: "Can anyone help me?" is not a good question, instead, the question should include what is currently done and what requirements are not met.
I also adjusted some smaller issues in the question text.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

With `Thread.sleep(4000)` you are simply pausing the whole Thread for 4000ms.

I don't know how exactly you can pause and unpause a thread from within itself, but I think it should be possible if you call the sleep method from another thread though.

Comment: I tried doing that but i kept getting errors.. Could you please post a simple example of what you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

```
        TimerTask repeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                 Panel.repaint();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");

        long period = 4000L;
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask, 0, period);
```

Notice that you can cancel the timer at any moment by calling: `Timer.cancel()`

Comment: I am so sorry but i forgot to mention. I have added a button that stops the animation. And i want to resume the animation by using the same button.. Like u know it is the start/stop button.. The progran is basically a rectangle moving in the screen and i want to start/stop moving by using the button

Answer (score 0):

When you start a thread, you can add a condition, under which the thread runs. If you change this, condition, you can pause the animation and it will resume where you stopped.

```
boolean pause;
thr = new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
  while(!thr.isInterrupted()&&pause==false){
        try{
             Thread.sleep(t);
        }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        action();   
   }
}
});
thr.start();
```